# Accessing Nuget Packages in Docker Container

Tags: c#, visual-studio, docker, .net-core, nuget

I need to build and run my .Net Core console app inside a Docker container.  The build of the VS sln works, and the nuget package restore works, but the console app doesn't run because it can't find the nuget dependencies - even though they are restored and present.  This entire question might boil down to needing a way to control where or how nuget packages are probed.

I'm using `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1` as my base image.  This is a multi-stage docker build, which means that stage 1 needs to copy the console app binaries and all the nuget files which were restored in stage 0. I presume this means I don't want the nuget packages to load into the usual nuget cache location. Assuming that, I figured the easiest way to solve this would be for stage 0 to restore all nuget packages directly beneath the console app's target build folder.

Also, I need to target x86 explicitly, so my docker file builds the "PlatformExtract" console app as follows:

```
RUN dotnet restore --packages .\PlatformExtract\bin\x86\Release\netcoreapp3.1 NeoAgent.sln
RUN dotnet build --no-restore --configuration Release -p:Platform=x86 NeoAgent.sln
```

When the build is done, as expected, all the nuget packages are found in folders beneath the console app.  However, when I run the app within the aforementioned container it fails.  My console app solution has "connector" plugin projects (i.e. DLLs) that the console app loads at runtime.  Here are examples of errors that result when the plugins are loaded and the associated nuget dependencies are not found:

```
Unhandled exception. System.InvalidOperationException: Dependency resolution failed for component C:\PlatformConnect\SqliteConnector.dll with error code -2147450740. Detailed error: Error:
  An assembly specified in the application dependencies manifest (SqliteConnector.deps.json) was not found:
    package: 'SQLitePCLRaw.lib.e_sqlite3', version: '2.0.2'
    path: 'runtimes/win-x86/native/e_sqlite3.dll'
```

I looked in the folder specified in the above path, and the DLL was there.  So the runtime simply isn't bothering to look in the folders directly beneath the console app exe.  I chose temporarily to remove the above "SqliteConnector" plugin, which only caused the next plugin to fail to load when it too was unable to load a nuget dependency:

```
Unhandled exception. System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to load types from assembly AzureBlobConnector, Version=1.
0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null. Unable to load one or more of the requested types.
Could not load file or assembly 'Azure.Core, Version=1.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=92742159e12e44c8'. The system cannot find the file specified.
 ---> System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: Unable to load one or more of the requested types.
```

How do I configure the application so that it will look for all nuget dependencies directly beneath the folder containing the main executable?

Also, in case it is relevant, I'm loading plugins using an `AssemblyLoadContext` much as described in [this article](https://cjansson.se/blog/post/creating-isolated-plugins-dotnetcore).

Comment: If you have nuget offline and need to restore from them you need to copy them to the final executable. check this repo out -> https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnContainers. You need to check the dockerfiles -> https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnContainers/blob/dev/src/Services/Basket/Basket.API/Dockerfile

Comment: What you want is to run `dotnet publish` which copies everything that your app needs to the specified location.  See the samples at https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/tree/master/samples.